# How to remove password from encrypted wallet with password?

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

Without using `dumpwallet` nor `dumpprivkey`, is there a way to take an encrypted wallet and making it decrypted so it can be used without entering a password?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have the password, you just want to make it so the wallet is not encrypted anymore, so you don't have to keep entering the password, correct?